# Any tips to making excel dsum faster?

Tags: performance, excel, worksheet-function

I am currently using a dsum to calculate some totals and I noticed excel has become really slow (needs 2 seconds per cell change).

This is the situation:

```
- I am trying to calculate 112 dsums to show in a chart;
- all dsums are queries on a table with 15 columns and +32k rows;
- all dsums have multiple criteria (5-6 constraints);
- the criteria uses both numerical and alpha-numerical constraints;
- i have the source table/range sorted;
- excel file is 3.4 mb in size;
```

(I am using excel 2007 on an 4 year old windows laptop)

Any ideas on what can be done to make it faster?

...other than reducing the number of dsums :P ====>>> already working on that one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options are:

Change Calculation to Manual and press F9 whenever you want to calculate

Try SUMIFS rather than DSUM

Exploit the fact that the data is sorted by using MATCH and COUNTIF to find the first row and count    of rows, then use OFFSET or INDEX to get the relevant subset of data    to feed to SUMIFS for the remaining constraints

Comment: Thanks Charles! Given the multiple conditions using several columns, I find it a lot more complex to use COUNTIF and similar functions. I will try to figure out an alternative using what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DSUMs you could also put it all in one or multiple Pivot tables - and then use GETPIVOTDATA to extract the data you need. The reading of the table will take up a bit of time (though 32k rows should be done below 1") - and then GETPIVOTDATA is lightning fast!

Downsides:

- You need to manually refresh the pivot when you get new data
- The pivot(s) need to be laid out so the requested data is show
- File size will increase (unless Pivot cache is not stored, the file loading takes longer)